# Trouble with an unwind/project on mongo C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to get an array of all points from reports so that they can be mapped. To do this I need an unwind/projection but I'm struggling to get my head around it.

The result is formatted like so..

```
"totalPoints": 200,
    "points": [
        {
            "itemId": "5e9592edb4959a52b8493f6d",
            "itemName": "Numquam hic minus repellat sequi.",
            "name": null,
            "longitude": null,
            "latitude": null
        },
...
```

As you can see I'm getting nulls for the bottom 3 items.

Here is the query I'm using

```
            var points = await _reportDocs.Aggregate()
                .Match(filter.GenerateFilter())
                .Unwind<IntelReport, IntelReportLocationUnwound>(x => x.Locations)
                .Project(x => new LocationDto
                {
                    ItemId = x.Id,
                    ItemName = x.Name,
                    Name = x.Location.Name,
                    Latitude = x.Location.Point.Coordinates[1],
                    Longitude = x.Location.Point.Coordinates[0]
                })
                .ToListAsync();
```

Here is the original report class (but I've took some stuff out which wasn't needed here)

```
 public class IntelReport
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string ReportTitle { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }

    }
```

and the classes I thought I needed to do the unwind...

```
 public class LocationDto
    {
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double? Longitude { get; set; }
        public double? Latitude { get; set; }
    }

    [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class IntelReportLocationUnwound
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("ReportTitle")]
        [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("locations")]
        [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
        public LocationForAgg Location { get; set; }
    }

    public class LocationForAgg
    {
        [BsonElement("name")]
        [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("point")]
        [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
        public PointForAgg Point { get; set; }
    }

    public class PointForAgg
    {
        [BsonElement("coordinates")]
        [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
        public double[] Coordinates { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) converts an array of subdocuments into a single subdocument so your data after `.Unwind<IntelReport, IntelReportLocationUnwound>(x => x.Locations)` will look like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e968bd5cc41498362cee2d2"), 
    "ReportTitle" : "aa", 
    "Locations" : { 
        "ItemId" : ObjectId("5e968bd5cc41498362cee2d3"), 
        "ItemName" : "Name", 
        "Name" : "N", 
        "Longitude" : 15, 
        "Latitude" : -24 
    } 
}
```

which means that you have to rethink the `IntelReportLocationUnwound` class definition. You can use the same type you had in `IntelReport` since MongoDB will only convert it from an array into a nested object:

```
public class IntelReportLocationUnwound
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("ReportTitle")]
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("Locations")]
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}
```

then you can modify your aggregation:

```
.Project(x => new LocationDto
        {
            ItemId = x.Id,
            ItemName = x.Name,
            Name = x.Location.Name,
            Latitude = x.Location.Latitude,
            Longitude = x.Location.Longitude
        })
```